# MediaPlayer: stop called in state 4

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an activity that has a VideoView that is asynchronously preparing a video:

```
Uri mUri = "uri to streaming video"
VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(mUri);
mVideoView.setMediaController(null);

mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

While it is "preparing" I show a ProgressDialog... if I press the back button during this state the following error is printed to ADB and the activity crashes silently with a short wait at a black screen:

```
E/MediaPlayer( 2204): stop called in state 4
E/MediaPlayer( 2204): error (-38, 0) 
W/ActivityManager(   59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45080368 com.myapp.VideoPlayerActivity}
```

What is the best way to stop a VideoView from preparing a video so you can exit an activity?

Note: I don't have access to the actual MediaPlayer object until the callback for the video being prepared is called:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player)
```

... which hasn't happened while the MediaPlayer/VideoView is "preparing".

Comment: NPike I am suffering from the same problem. have you solved the problem ? then how ? Please share knowledge.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to fix this?  I know the thread is old but I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested it my self but you should be able to `reset()` the MediaPlayer when you are in preparing state.

Comment: its not possible to get a MediaPlayer reference before the video is ready, so its not possible reset the Media Player

Answer (score 1):

Try calling MediaPlayer.prepare() before doing MediaPlayer.stop() when back button is pressed (implement onPause or onStop activity method)

Comment: its not possible to get a MediaPlayer reference before the video is ready, so its not possible call MediaPlayer.prepare()